# make user-defined labels and items aligned left

Tags: align, enumerate, itemize, labels, leftmargin

I hope to make a unordered list aligned left, i.e. the user-defined labels and items are aligned to the left.

For example:

```
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, labelsep=*, align=left, itemsep=-0.1cm, font=\normalfont]
    \item[$\mathcal{G}$] First item.
    \item[$\mathcal{M}$] Second item.
    \item[$\mathcal{S}$] Third item.
\end{itemize}
```

All of the labels are aligned left, but items are not so neat.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please, always provide complete small document which reproduce your problem, What you mean with "not so neat"? Completing your code fragment in small document gives exšpected (nice) result ...

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

    
\begin{document}        
    
\begin{description}[leftmargin=!,labelwidth= 20pt]
    \item[$\mathcal{G}$] First item.
    \item[$\mathcal{M}$] Second item.
    \item[$\mathcal{S}$] Third item.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]